# Perform two-way ANOVA (one observation per mean) in R?

Tags: r, anova

How do we do two-way ANOVA (one observation per mean), as testing H_A in Section 8.5 in Seber and Lee's Linear Regression Analysis, in R?
Note that the linear model for this case doesn't have interaction between the row and column factors.

For example, I want to test in the following 3 x 2 table, if the mean of each row is the same.

5 | 4
7 | 6
4 | 7

Note that I used `lm` for one-way ANOVA, but couldn't find out which function and arguments to do two-way ANOVA (one observation per mean). I am not trying to implement it in R.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Is your problem really with R, or with understanding ANOVA?  How would you approach this problem by hand or using any other software?

Comment: With R. I understand how to calculate by hand.

Comment: If your real data are non-negative integers, I wouldn't use a straight ANOVA.

Comment: @Glen_b: (1) what do you use? Why? (2) My question is for self-educational purpose.

Comment: It depends on what the data were. If they were counts, I'd use a GLM (Poisson or binomial or perhaps negative binomial, depending on circumstances).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
y = scan()
  5  4
  7  6
  4  7

rowfactor=rep(1:3,each=2)
colfactor=rep(1:2,times=3)
y2w=data.frame(y=y,r=factor(rowfactor),c=factor(colfactor))
twowayfit=lm(y~r+c,y2w)
summary(twowayfit)
anova(twowayfit)
```

or just

```
summary(aov(y~r+c,data=y2w))
```

in place of the end parts of the above

If those data were counts, the `lm` line would be replaced with a very similar call to `glm`, but which specified a suitable family.

---

An alternate, but equivalent way to set it up:

```
y = read.table(stdin(),header=FALSE)
  5  4
  7  6
  4  7

y2w = stack(y)
y2w$rf=factor(rep(1:3,times=2))
aov(values~ind+rf,y2w)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am confused about `r+c` in `lm(y~r+c,y2w)`. I tried `d=c(5,4,7,6,4,7); a=c(rep("A",2), rep("B",2), rep("C",2)); b=c("D","E","F","D","E","F"); summary(lm(d ~ a*b))` instead, and F test result is `NAN`. What differences are between `r*c` and `r+c` ?  Did I  perform some other test instead?

Comment: You fitted a model with interactions. You don't have enough data to fit a two-way with interactions. `r*c` is the same as `r+c+r:c`, and `r:c` are the interactions.